# Select a column from subquery inside select?

Tags: sql

How can I SELECT the Attr1 from subquery to the parent query? I have tried to use Average.Attr1 but doesn't work.

> not a single-group group function

```
SELECT SUM(Report.Attr1), 
       SUM(Report.Attr2), 
       SUM(Report.Attr3), 
       0
FROM {Report}, 
(
    SELECT AVG(Report.Attr1),
           AVG(Report.Attr2),
           AVG(Report.Attr3)
    FROM Report
    WHERE 
        StartDate <= Report.Date AND
        Report.Date <= EndDate
    GROUP BY Report.Attr1, Report.Attr2, Report.Attr3
) Average
WHERE 
    StartDate <= Report.Date AND
    Report.Date <= EndDate
```

Comment: AVG(Report.Attr]) has a ] rather than a 1

Comment: please add some sample data

Comment: Oops thanks, my edit was wrong before I posted this question. It's not the cause of the error though.

Comment: having a column named "Date" in a table can be very risky since it is a reserved word.

Comment: the inner select is not joined to the outer making it to a cartesian join. Maybe that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: The sub-query's group by makes no sense at all. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Make it easy to help you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can add aliases to those aggregate functions, so that you can use them in the outer query

```
SELECT SUM(avg_attr1), 
       SUM(avg_attr2), 
       SUM(avg_attr3), 
       0
FROM {Report}, 
(
    SELECT AVG(Report.Attr1) as avg_attr1,
           AVG(Report.Attr2) as avg_attr2,
           AVG(Report.Attr3) as avg_attr3
    ...
```

Or if you just want to limit on them, then you could use the HAVING clause together with the GROUP BY

```
...
      GROUP BY Report.Attr1, Report.Attr2, Report.Attr3
      HAVING AVG(Report.Attr1) > {SomeNumber}
) Average
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I get it to work by:

```
WITH REPORT (STARTDATE,ENDDATE,DATE1,ATTR1,ATTR2,ATTR3)AS(
SELECT DATE '2018-01-01',DATE '2018-02-01',DATE '2018-01-11', 1,2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-01-01',DATE '2018-02-01',DATE '2018-01-11',1,2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select date '2018-01-01',DATE '2018-02-01',DATE '2018-01-11',1,2,3 from dual 
)

SELECT SUM(Report.Attr1), 
       SUM(Report.Attr2), 
       SUM(REPORT.ATTR3), 
       0,
       average.a,average.b,average.c
FROM REPORT, 
(
    SELECT AVG(REPORT.ATTR1) A,
           AVG(REPORT.ATTR2) B ,
           AVG(Report.Attr3) c
    FROM Report
    WHERE 
        STARTDATE <= REPORT.DATE1 AND
        Report.Date1 <= EndDate
    GROUP BY Report.Attr1, Report.Attr2, Report.Attr3
) Average
WHERE 
    STARTDATE <= REPORT.DATE1 AND
    REPORT.DATE1 <= ENDDATE
    GROUP BY 0,
       average.a,average.b,average.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to them by giving an Alias name. Now if you say, `Average.attr` you get the value corresponding to  `Report.Attr1`

```
SELECT SUM(Report.Attr1), 
           SUM(Report.Attr2), 
           SUM(Report.Attr3), 
           0,
           Average.attr
    FROM {Report}, 
    (
        SELECT AVG(Report.Attr1) as attr,
               AVG(Report.Attr2),
               AVG(Report.Attr3)
        FROM Report
        WHERE 
            StartDate <= Report.Date AND
            Report.Date <= EndDate
        GROUP BY Report.Attr1, Report.Attr2, Report.Attr3
    ) Average
    WHERE 
        StartDate <= Report.Date AND
        Report.Date <= EndDate
```